# jQuery Sliding a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to slide a div up, and after it has slided up completely, I want to slide the other `<div>` down (which is by default hidden).

I am trying following code, it does what I want, but I only don't get the effect that the div slides down after the first has slided up completely, it looks like the div starts appearing as soon the other div starts sliding above.

So how can I make it wait till the first div slides up completely and then it starts sliding down.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="down"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="hidediv">Hide me</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.up{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    display: block;
}

.down{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#hidediv").click(function () {
  $(".up").slideUp(800);
  $(".down").slideDown(800);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hFyvw/

Comment: This is a very well-formatted question

Comment: Not sure if that "Hide me" is you final text or what the complete functionality would be, but I just got thinking that it might be annoying for visitors if they are really tying to get rid of the box by clicking "Hide me", and then another box just slides in its place.

Comment: @Joonas no, i just wrote for the example. I dont have any link to show/hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the callback function of slideUp:

```
$("#hidediv").click(function () {
  $(".up").slideUp(800, function () {
    $(".down").slideDown(800);
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah, thanks Adrian ;-) What's wrong about 4 spaces per indentation? Seems the way SO does it by default.

Comment: Who's that Adrian you're talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Try Using it in a callback:

```
$("#hidediv").click(function () {
  $(".up").slideUp(800, function () {
    $(".down").slideDown(800);
  });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFyvw/1/)

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I accepted @m7o answer, as both are same answers but he replied 10 seconds earlier :)